# How to document APIs in postman in the following conditions?

Tags: postman

We have a series of GET requests api, say in the format of

```
curl -XGET ip-address/api-keywords
```

These kind of requests generate a JSON responses.

Now the issue here is when I document using Postman,we do not want the ip address to be exposed. How to edit that in postman?.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup environments in Postman that will let you use variables. Then in your collection, different developers or users can setup their own environments and variables. See https://www.getpostman.com/docs/environments

Comment: In case the link changes, could you please edit your answer to include the relevant portions here? Thanks!